# Fill external imported svg file

Tags: css, angular, svg, sass, fill

I'm using Angular 5 and i would fill my white svg image.

I have a svg file like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><title>ic_calendar</title><g id="Level_2" data-name="Level 2"><g id="screen"><path d="M18.5,5.11a2.55,2.55,0,0,0-.58-1.68,2.27,2.27,0,0,0-1.7-.71H14.85v-1a.68.68,0,1,0-1.35,0v1H6.39v-1A.67.67,0,0,0,5.72,1,.68.68,0,0,0,5,1.68v1H3.75A2.15,2.15,0,0,0,1.5,5.09V16.4a2.71,2.71,0,0,0,.69,2A2.08,2.08,0,0,0,3.7,19H16.34a2.14,2.14,0,0,0,2.15-2.26C18.51,15.07,18.5,5.57,18.5,5.11Zm-15.65,0h0c0-.71.27-1,.9-1H5v1a.69.69,0,0,0,.68.68.68.68,0,0,0,.67-.68v-1H13.5v1a.68.68,0,1,0,1.35,0v-1H16.2a1,1,0,0,1,.71.26,1.17,1.17,0,0,1,.24.72V6.84H2.85Zm14.3,11.64c0,.78-.52.9-.81.91H3.7a.73.73,0,0,1-.56-.2,1.49,1.49,0,0,1-.29-1V8.2h14.3Z" style="fill:#fff"/><rect width="20" height="20" style="fill:none"/></g></g></svg>
```

So, i'm importing it through this code:

```
<svg class="myClass">
<use xlink:href="assetFolder/ic_calendar.svg#Level_2"></use>
</svg>
```

However, i can't change the svg image style and i can't fill it.
I tried, via sass, to add the following:

```
svg { fill: blue; }
```

or

```
path { fill: blue; }
```

But nothing...
Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- Presentation attributes `svg` have the highest priority and can not
  be changed with the`css`. Therefore, they need to be removed if you
  want to change the color of the `svg` objects from the external table
  `CSS`
- When using the `<use>` command, `svg` objects fall into the `shadow  DOM`
- In order to stylize these objects, you must use forced inheritance

  `path {
  fill:inherit;
  stroke:inherit;
  }`

*Below is an example where objects are called from the `<defs>` section with the `use` command and stylized from the external table `css`*

```css
  path {
 fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
 }
 #screen {
  fill:dodgerblue;
 }
 rect {fill:#D5D5D5;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<title>ic_calendar</title>

<defs>
<g id="screen">
<rect id="rect1" width="20" height="20"  />
<path  d="M18.5,5.11a2.55,2.55,0,0,0-.58-1.68,2.27,2.27,0,0,0-1.7-.71H14.85v-1a.68.68,0,1,0-1.35,0v1H6.39v-1A.67.67,0,0,0,5.72,1,.68.68,0,0,0,5,1.68v1H3.75A2.15,2.15,0,0,0,1.5,5.09V16.4a2.71,2.71,0,0,0,.69,2A2.08,2.08,0,0,0,3.7,19H16.34a2.14,2.14,0,0,0,2.15-2.26C18.51,15.07,18.5,5.57,18.5,5.11Zm-15.65,0h0c0-.71.27-1,.9-1H5v1a.69.69,0,0,0,.68.68.68.68,0,0,0,.67-.68v-1H13.5v1a.68.68,0,1,0,1.35,0v-1H16.2a1,1,0,0,1,.71.26,1.17,1.17,0,0,1,.24.72V6.84H2.85Zm14.3,11.64c0,.78-.52.9-.81.91H3.7a.73.73,0,0,1-.56-.2,1.49,1.49,0,0,1-.29-1V8.2h14.3Z"  />
</g>
</defs> 

<use xlink:href="#screen" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline style on your svg path - `style="fill:#fff"`. Inline styles take precedence over styles in a CSS stylesheet. But thats what `!important` is for!

either update your style to this:

`path { fill: blue !important; }`

OR simply remove the inline styling.